# What the best way to access client side generated controls/data in ASP.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, repeater

I created a table of form fields with ASP.net and the repeater control which contains data from a database.

Now the user can add rows which will add a new row with jQuery to the repeater control (which is a html table when it's rendered. So I'm adding these rows to the client side html table and not to the repeaters data source).

When the user is posting the data to the server I'm able to access the edited rows directly from the repeater but of course, the new jQuery generated rows aren't stored in the repeater.

I also took a look at the Request.Form variables, but there are just the repeater controls too (If I'm wrong with my assumption that this should be that way, please give me some sign).

The only one solution I see is to store all rows data in a json object and pass it to the server. But it would be great if there is another solution without using Javascript to post the data.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have to say: it's possible just by accessing the Form.Request Data. It's important, when you're generating new fields on client side, you have to set new and different name attribute values for all the form fields because Request.Form contains the fields values grouped by the name values. And if you're generating new rows like I do with a clone() of another row, they would be identically and you can't see them in the Request.Form if you don't change them.

Another solution is to save all the form data in a JSON object and at it to a hidden field. Server side you can easy deserialize the JSON Object (maybe you need a JSON library first) and access your data. There's no need for a AJAX request.

I would say, the best way is JSON Object way. I did it with the Request.Form to write less Javscript and more server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

IMO - you should use ajax post for the altered/ new rows only.

you dont need to post the page.
when you send with ajax using json - you should build a json object which will contain the info of the new /edited rows and the server ( using ashx) can update DB.

please notice there isnt a refresh of the page.

p.s. you should update the rows count - from the reply from the ashx response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to do this strictly with jQuery and asp.net.  You could use an `UpdatePanel`.  Otherwise `ViewState` will likely cause you some grief.

Comment: The problem with UpdatePanel is it makes a postback all the time adding a new row. I think this is really unnecessary and causes a lack of performance/speed when the user adds a new row (for example when entering tab to access new row which will be added exact at this time).

Comment: I agree with the problem you describe with UpdatePanels.  I'm not sure of another way to handle it except getting out of ASP.net web forms and into MVC applications. ViewState is a nightmare.